# Instantiating vs Injection

Tags: dependency-injection

I'm trying to better understand the pros/cons of instantiating vs injecting in a web application type development.

1. What are the pros & cons for each?
2. When should they be used (what sort of scenario we looking at)?

Comment: see [What is the problem with “Pros and Cons”?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.
**pros:** testability, external configuration of per client implementation rather than "in the code" implementation (think if / else if for each new client). logic is abstracted away

**cons:** adds complexity, logic is abstracted away

2.
You should inject "behavioral" implementations which can have variance based on implementation or environment. Things which don't change could be instantiated

**Long winded answer:** 
Injecting gives you the greatest flexibility of configuration of concrete implementations / instantiations. It's a layer of abstraction which allows you to define the "behaviors" of the implementations (the ins / outs) so you can build your entire app around expectations. Then the "fulfillers" of those expectations can be configured.

Client A uses SQL database, Client B uses Oracle database.

Client A calls a method: public User GetUserByID(int id)

Client B calls a method: public User GetUserByID(int id)

if we create an interface which contains something like:

```
public interface IUserServices{
     User GetUserByID(int id)
}
```

We can use an Injector to configure which implementation to use. 
something like this on app startup for client A:

```
Bind<ClientA_UserServices>.To<IUserServices>();
```

and for client B:

```
Bind<ClientB_UserServices>.To<IUserServices>();
```

and in the App:

```
public class DoSomethingWithUserService{
      IUserServices _svc;

      public DoSomethingWithUserService(IUserServices svc)
      {
            _svc = svc;
      }

      public void doSomething()
      {
            User theUser = _svc.GetUserByID(User.ID);
      }
}
```

now, in addition, you can now unit test DoSomethingWithUserService and pass in a test implementation IUserServices which may use static test data, or Mock data.